# adding columns to this vba code for hiding and showing columns just llke rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Sub Hide_Show_Rows()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    
    StartRow = 22 'Change this as per your data
    EndRow = 36 'Change this as per your data
    
    For i = StartRow To EndRow
        If Range("c4").Value = "NEW REGIME" And i >= 22 And i <= 27 Then
            Rows(i).Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("c4").Value = "OLD REGIME" And i >= 29 And i <= 36 Then
            Rows(i).Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows(i).Hidden = False
            End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

i did not achive anything

Comment: First of all the posted code will not compile. Secondly, what do you want to achieve resp. what is your issue? Thats is not clear for me. If one removes the signature for the `Worksheet_Change` event the code works for me but, of course,  your expectation might be different.

Comment: Not sure why you have a `Sub` inside another `Sub` but VBA does not work like that. Remove this `Sub Hide_Show_Rows()` so you can least get it to compile, then you can test it.

Comment: since you dont have a trigger remove the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` line